# Refactoring MySQL query

Tags: sql, mysql-5.7

We came up with this query:

```
SELECT tn1.* FROM tree_node tn1
WHERE tn1.type != "folder" AND tn1.parent IN (
    SELECT tn.id FROM tree_node tn
    LEFT JOIN tree_node_access tna ON tna.tree_node_id = tn.id
    WHERE (tn.project_id = 50 AND tna.access = 0 AND (tna.user_id = 8 OR tna.user_group_id IN (26)))
) OR tn1.id IN (
    SELECT tn.id FROM tree_node tn
    LEFT JOIN tree_node_access tna ON tna.tree_node_id = tn.id
    WHERE (tn.project_id = 50 AND tna.access = 0 AND (tna.user_id = 8 OR tna.user_group_id IN (26)))
)
```

But it must be possible to not have to repeat the subquery twice, as that query is exactly the same.

Is there a way to refactor this query?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). Incidentally, while not necessarily incorrect, I find LEFT JOINs with OR conditions on the joined table incomprehensible.

Comment: I think you could rewrite it with the subquery as a derived table, and join to the original table with an OR condition. I am at work right now, so I'll try and give it a go later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the or with UNION and replace the subqueries with JOINs:

```
SELECT tn1.*
FROM tree_node tn1
INNER JOIN tree_node tn
ON tn1.parent=tn.id
LEFT JOIN tree_node_access tna
ON tna.tree_node_id = tn.id
WHERE tn1.type != 'folder'
AND (tn.project_id = 50 AND tna.access = 0 AND (tna.user_id = 8 OR tna.user_group_id IN (26)))
UNION
SELECT tn1.*
FROM tree_node tn1
INNER JOIN tree_node tn
ON tn.id=tn1.id
LEFT JOIN tree_node_access tna
ON tna.tree_node_id = tn.id
WHERE (tn.project_id = 50 AND tna.access = 0 AND (tna.user_id = 8 OR tna.user_group_id IN (26)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which MySQL version you are using. In MySQL 8.x you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) for it.

For example:

```
with
a as (
  SELECT tn.id FROM tree_node tn
  LEFT JOIN tree_node_access tna ON tna.tree_node_id = tn.id
  WHERE (tn.project_id = 50 AND tna.access = 0 
    AND (tna.user_id = 8 OR tna.user_group_id IN (26)))
)
SELECT tn1.* FROM tree_node tn1
WHERE tn1.type != "folder" AND tn1.parent IN (select id from a)
   OR tn1.id IN (select id from a)
```

Comment: That looks really nice, but unfortunately, we are on version 5.7 currently